# Not all rows showing in map view for fusion table

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I have a Google fusion table that contains about 50k rows with kml data. When I bring up the map view in the fusion tables UI I only see data for about a few thousand rows.

When I do a spatial query to return data that fits within the boundaries, I don't get any results for rows after the first few thousand.

I looked at my kml and it appears to be correct. Is there some limitation that I am running into or should I be looking at something else. If needed I can provide the table id if someone wants to look at it.

Comment: The limit is 100k records, everything below should work. Are all the records already geocoded? Can you provide a link to your table?

Comment: I hadn't done the geocode. I went and selected that option now but it is staying at 0% so I don't know if it is working or not. Here is the link. https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=16dZnxxkEz4XVrR8O1UcaNXgUYo86sY_mOw1G5BM

Comment: I guess it takes a while for 50k records to geocode. But this is a prerequisite to display the data on the map. If a record is not yet geocoded, the location column for that record has a yellow background. Are you still seeing too few records on the map?

Comment: Does kml need to be geocoded? That is what I have in my geometry column that I am trying to map. The progress bar never goes above 0% so I don't think there is anything for it to do, or it is broken.

Comment: Actually kml does not need to be geocoded. I [checked the docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTables), and there is another limit that you likely hit: if you have more than 500 features per tile, they are thinned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KML does not need to be geocoded.

KML can sometimes have very large files, even if only 50K rows. If your original file was very large, (>100 MB), you may be encountering performance issues. I'd recommend making the file smaller (simpler) and start again.

If you are running into an issue with more than 500 items for a given map tile, more items will appear as you zoom in. (Because more map tiles are used to cover the same area.)

-Rebecca

Comment: I think the problem was my kml was very large for every row. I did a reduce on the number of points to 1/20th the number of points. This worked and I still have a polygon that works.